# jquery response is not comming as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am basically editing and displaying the data its in jquery popup but response is not comming as html its text here is my code
centerPopup(); and loadPopup(); both working fine but my popup with data is text not html becouse its not clickable

```
function edit_this(id){
var id_to_edit = id;
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
    url: 'https://www.xyz.com/userftp/fawad/test/edit_schedule.php',
    data: 'id_to_edit=' + id_to_edit,
    dataType:'html',
    success : function(response){
    $("#popupContact").html(response);
    centerPopup();
    loadPopup();

    }
});     
 }
```

Comment: could you please explain : `becouse its not clickable` ?

Comment: popup comes with data extracted from edit_schedule.php puts in its required elements but its not HTML its just Text Becouse i cant click in that popup anf if i click nothing happens its just like an image

Comment: What kind of response are you getting? What is the PHP script source code for what's being outputted. 
Your jQuery seems to be alright, but that's no use if your response is sent with the wrong headers, encoding, etc...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I got confused. Here's the correction.

The type of data of the response is also determined by the server method you're calling.

Even if you specify the `dataType` attribute, I'd make sure the HTTP Response is sending out the appropriate content type (text/html).

Comment: when i alert(response) its all html what i need but i dont know y this looks like an image. dataType = 'html' means "html": Treat the response as HTML (plain text); included script tags are evaluated. shall i remove this ????

Comment: i removed dataType = 'html'  still its an image like

Comment: Matteo you are wrong. dataType is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server, so 'html' is fine. Look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I checked and you're right, I don't know how I got confused about this, since I use jquery ajax calls everyday. I think I need a vacation...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to see the text in the div and in the alert, the problem seems to be more with your html markup than the ajax request.

Copy the response text on another blank html page and see if it works as expected. If it works the problem is with the markup of the page on which you are inserting the response.